# Dúvida sobre uso de diretório virtual no IIS e filetable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, iis

Eu preciso armazenar arquivos em um `FileTable`. Como não sei o caminho local onde os arquivos que estão no `FileTable` ficam, mapeei o caminho de rede do diretório do `FileTable`, e assim acesso o diretório do `FileTable`.

Eu preciso fazer com que a aplicação salve os arquivos no `FileTable`, então criei um diretório virtual apontando para o mapeamento.

Está dando erro 404 (*not found*) então eu queria saber: posso usar o diretório virtual para esse fim e o problema seja alguma configuração, ou eu não posso utilizar o diretório virtual nesse caso?

Comment: Acho **muito** errada essa abordagem. O certo seria você escrever uma pequena aplicação que acesse o diretório e devolva o arquivo que você quer, mas com o banco intermediando.

Comment: Como não sei onde fica o diretório do FileTable localmente na maquina (sinceramente acho que não tem como acessar localmente, só via compartilhamento mesmo) esse foi um jeito que eu pensei, imaginei que era mesmo uma "gambiarra", vou pensar em outra coisa, algo mais parecido com o que você sugeriu. Obrigado.